# How To Make Responsive positioned inside a Stack in flutter and how to control the space between elements inside the row and the row inside coulmn

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the result in tablet and phone the different is shown:

[image: This is The Result in tablet and phone the different is show]

This is main design I build it:

[image: this is main design]

How to solve it?

This is my code in this design

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

import '../../../../core/app_color.dart';
import '../../../../core/app_style.dart';
import '../../../../models/product_model.dart';

class ProductView extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductView({Key? key, required this.productModel}) : super(key: key);
  final ProductModel productModel;
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  final double _height = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double percent = (productModel.disPrice - productModel.price) /
        productModel.disPrice *
        100;
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColor.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 20),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 8,
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Stack(children: [
            Container(
              width: width * 0.42,
              height: height * 0.21,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(productModel.imageUrl),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: height * 0.01,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Container(
                width: 48.31,
                height: 19,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  color: AppColor.lightBlue,
                  // border: Border.all(color: AppColor.white)),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  productModel.productNameType,
                  style: bodyStyle1.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 7.sp, color: AppColor.white),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            //height * 0.026
            //width * 0.04
            Align(
              widthFactor: width * 0.42 / width * 12,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColor.lightBlue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                child: const FaIcon(
                  Icons.favorite_outline_rounded,
                  color: AppColor.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          Text(
            productModel.productName,
            style: bodyStyle1.copyWith(color: AppColor.lightBlue),
          ),
          Text(
            productModel.productType,
            style: bodyStyle2.copyWith(fontSize: 11.sp, color: AppColor.grey),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Text(
                '${productModel.price}',
                style: bodyStyle1.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 12.sp,
                    color: AppColor.lightGreyHeader,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
              ),
              Text(
                '${productModel.disPrice}',
                style: bodyStyle1.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 12.sp,
                  color: AppColor.black,
                ),
              ),
              percent != 0
                  ? Container(
                      width: 48.31,
                      height: 19,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          border: Border.all(color: AppColor.lightBlue)),
                      child: Text(
                        '${percent.toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
                        style: bodyStyle2.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 9.sp, color: AppColor.lightBlue),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to solve the responsive positioned?

And how to control the space between elements inside the row?

I tired of try and try and can not find any solution of that issue.

Comment: so you want to create a responsive positioned of the badge?

Comment: Yes how can i do that